# Как сделать сортировку по нескольким полям Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, listview, сортировка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Yii2 сделать сортировку по двум атрибутам???

> Latest | Reviews_count | Moust Popularity | Highest_rated | _____ |
>   Monthly | Weekly | Daily

Есть атрибуты сортировки расположенные в таком порядке на странице. В методе `search` модели, настраиваю свойство `query` датаПровайдера, и задаю по каким полям делать сортировку, таким образом при нажатии на ссылки, сортировка происходит по тому, по чему жмякнул. Установил в `Sort` свойство `enableMultiSort = true`, таким образом есть возможность жмякать по разным ссылкам и устанавливать сортировку по нескольким полям. Мне нужен поиск по двум атрибутам только, то есть жмякаем на одно поле, сортировка происходит по нему, жмякнул по другому оно становится основным а первое становиться второстепенным, при нажатии на третье поле оно становится основным, а то поле которое было нажато первым больше по нему не сортируется. Причем из атрибутов `monthly`, `daily` и `weekly` можно выбрать только одно из трех. Во вью генерю ссылки через `Sort::link()`.

Вот что в модели `Search`

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = Coupons::find();

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $query->select([
            self::tableName() . '.*',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\follow\models\Follow::tableName() . ' WHERE shop_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.shop_id AND user_id = ' . Yii::$app->user->id . ') as followed',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::tableName() . ' WHERE item_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND type = ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::TYPE_COUPON . ' AND action = ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::ACTION_LIKE . ') as popular',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id ) as general',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400) . '" )) as daily',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400 * 7) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400 * 7) . '" )) as weekly',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400 * 30) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400 * 30) . '" )) as monthly'
        ]);
    } else {
        $query->select([
            self::tableName() . '.*',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::tableName() . ' WHERE item_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND type = ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::TYPE_COUPON . ' AND action = ' . \app\modules\likes\models\Like::ACTION_LIKE . ') as popular',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id ) as general',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400) . '" )) as daily',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400 * 7) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400 * 7) . '" )) as weekly',
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . \app\modules\coupons\models\CouponsViews::tableName() . ' WHERE coupon_id = ' . self::tableName() . '.id AND ( date BETWEEN "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 86400 * 30) . '" AND "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 86400 * 30) . '" )) as monthly'
        ]);
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ],
    ]);

    $attributes['separator'] = '|';
    $attributes['enableMultiSort'] = true;

    $attributes['attributes'] = [
        'Latest' => [
            'asc' => ['id' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['id' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
        'Best_rated' => [
            'asc' => ['popular' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['popular' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
        'Daily' => [
            'asc' => ['daily' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['daily' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
        'Weekly' => [
            'asc' => ['weekly' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['weekly' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
        'Monthly' => [
            'asc' => ['monthly' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['monthly' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
        'Most_popular' => [
            'asc' => ['general' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['general' => SORT_ASC],
        ]
    ];
    $attributes['defaultOrder'] = ['Latest' => SORT_ASC];

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $attributes['attributes']['For_followed_shops'] = [
            'asc' => ['followed' => SORT_DESC],
            'desc' => ['followed' => SORT_ASC]
        ];
    }

    $dataProvider->setSort($attributes);
    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    $query->andFilterWhere(['in', 'status', $this->status]);
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'shop_id' => $this->shop_id,
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Active Data Provider есть свойство, отвечающее за возможность сортировки по нескольким полям. Для этого в функцию `search`, отвечающую за поисковую форму модели добавьте:

```
$dataProvider->sort->enableMultiSort = true;
```

[#$enableMultiSort-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html#$enableMultiSort-detail)

Comment: Да читал об этом свойстве, изначально так и пробовал сделать, но как при включенном мультисорте отменять сортировку по какому-то атрибуту? допустим один раз кликнул, вторым кликом отключил сортировку по полю